# Cannot create anchor which can send POST request in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing an exercise from a book called Agile Web Development. The mission is that:

The users can add product to the cart when they kick the item image.
So I wrap the image tag into an anchor tag. Just like `<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), line_items_path(:product_id => product), html_options = {:method => :post} %>`

It seems to be fine which I kick the image, but it does not add anything into the cart.
I checked out the [discussion in book's website](http://pragprog.com/wikis/wiki/Pt-D-1), some of the solutions are similar to my one. But they also don't works.

Code is going to run when I kick the image:

```
# POST /line_items
# POST /line_items.json
def create
  # for exercise only
  session[:couter] = nil

  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product=>product)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code that gets run when you click the image? Or is the problem that the function you want is not getting run?

Comment: You cannot send POST requests with normal links. You have to use forms for this (buttons or inputs with type button or image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is going on.
It is the problem of the book, not the rails.

The original `<%= javascript_tag 'application %>'`

The book taught me change it to`<%= javascript_include_tag :default %>`

So I cannot import the javascript Library :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `button_to`, not `link_to`.  You can't send a `POST` request from an anchor link.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: Actually Rails' `link_to` will dynamically create a form for you and post it using JavaScript, so you can, in a way, initiate a POST request with an anchor link.

Comment: I love Stack Overflow.  Thank you.

Comment: I figured out what is going on. The book called me to change the javascript_tag :default instead of original javascript_tag 'application'

Comment: You should put that in an actual answer so it'll be easier to find.  Was thinking about it in the car later and figured it was most likely a JavaScript thing, but forgot to come back and say so later.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You want something like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), line_items_path(:product_id => product), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: it comes the same result with my code :( , just listing line items and not redirecting to the cart.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but do you have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: I have enabled JavaScript. Does your code work on your computer ?

Comment: I figured out what is going on. The book called me to change the javascript_tag :default instead of original javascript_tag 'application'